# 2D array with variable second dimension: compiler handling investigation

Tags: arrays, c

I read that for C multi-dimensional arrays, except for the first dimension, other array dimensionss should be fixed, i.e. bound
To investigate the above, I wrote the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {  
int N; 
double data2D[4][N]; 
scanf("%d",&N);
int i=0,j=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
for (j=0;j<N;j++)
   data2D[i][j]=i*N+j;
    printf("[%d,%d]\n",i,j);       
}

double Number=data2D[3][0];
printf(" the value=%f\n",Number);
}
```

I ran the above code and its variants with N value equal 5.

When I ran the above code, I got the following ouput:

```
[0,1]
[1,0]
[2,0]
[3,0]
the value=0.000000
```

When I moved scanf before the declaration of the array, I get

```
[0,5]
[1,5]
[2,5]
[3,5]
 the value=15.000000
[correct!]
```

Using the original program, I moved "int N;" before main(), I get

```
[1104140288,8388609]
 the value=0.000000
```

Is there any explanation to the above, especially the last 2? What the rule stated at the start of my message?

Thank you

Comment: `int N; double data2D[4][N]; scanf("%d",&N);` The `N` needs a value *before* you define the array. If you later change the value of `N` the array size does not change.

Comment: yes, that what I read. But my program worked fine in my second test, see above

Comment: That is what I meant. `N` must have the value you need before you define the array.

Comment: In short, put the `double` line _after_ the `scanf` line. Then, `N` will have a value so that `data2D` will be defined with the correct/desired dimensions.

Comment: @Weather,@Craig. Thank you. I fully understand you. Should I not read much on the results of the 2 other tests (that  what concerned me more )

Comment: If you are now doing it correctly, you need not be concerned with what happened when you did it incorrectly, because it can be confusing.